# What is the aim of FunctionalTest in PlayFramework?

Tags: playframework, functional-testing

I'm writing tests for my project, and after the Unit Tests, I'm now
writing FunctionalTest.

But between the aim of Functional vs Selenium test, I'm a bit lost.

Is the functional test are just here to test if, whatever I sent to
any page (mostly in POST), it should return what I expect (200, 302,
404, 500), or is there more ? (like test if the page returned is the
one I expect (like "Login page"? or this test should be in Selenium?)

Because so far, my F tests are just a bunch of functions with an
`assertStatus` for each, and I feel it's a bit useless.
I believe I can do more, but don't know why.

What do you test in your Functional tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question, it is probably easier to look at all three types of tests alongside each other.

**Unit Test** - To test an individual unit of code. For example, if I had an `Item` class, which made up part of a eCommerce site, I would have a number of Unit tests to test that the Item class functioned as expected. This may include a test to prove that the search function returns items that match specific criteria.

**Functional Test** - To test that when individual units are brought together, they work together as expected. For example, for the search function to work, we would expect to send a specific RESTful URL to search for an item, which would return a specific response. It would use our controller, and model classes to execute the code and achieve the complete function.

**Acceptance Test** - Also known as Selenium tests are much larger set of tests. These test a scenario that a user may run through, that may cover many functional tests, that in turn may encompass many unit tests. These are concerned more with processing a user journey or a scenario, rather than individual pieces of functionality.

As for the types of asserts that are used in FunctionalTests, I have also used `assertFalse` and `assertTrue` by using the `getContent` method on the response object.

Comment: Ok so functionnal tests are quite simple to make them if I understand correctly. Just have to test the expected return status. By getContent and assertTrue/false, what do you test ? if the content is not empty ?

Comment: I test if the content is a certain type. For example, I have tested that if 1 item is returned, then the content contains 'Found 1 item' and if 2 items are expected then the content contains, 'Found 2 items', to ensure plurals work.

Comment: And this shouldn't be more best suited in the Selenium tests ? (that's where I'm lost :/)

Comment: Maybe. But this tests a single function, without anything else, just that single functional requirement has been achieved. The acceptance test may include one or more functional tests...